# Mobile menu: clicking parent link reveals submenu but also goes to parent page directly

Tags: javascript

Usually, by default, I always saw that on mobile device clicking on the parent menu reveals submenu only and then if you click it again it opens the URL. But not on this site I'm working on, any ideas why it might override the default browser function and opens directly the parent link after the first click?

```
<nav id="nav">
<ul id="menu-primary-navigation" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-30"><a href="/our-services">Services</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-4216" class=""><a href="/service-one">Service 1</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-4215" class=""><a href="/service-two">Service 2</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-4217" class=""><a href="/service-three">Service 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-1125" class=""><a href="/about">About</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1139" class=""><a href="/events">Events</a></li>
</ul></nav>
```

Comment: Please provide any code you have specific issues with in your question.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say whitout more information, but it will try next changes:

```
<nav id="nav">
<ul id="menu-primary-navigation" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-30"><a>Services</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-4216" class=""><a href="/our-services/service-one">Service 1</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-4215" class=""><a href="/our-services/service-two">Service 2</a></li>
            <li id="menu-item-4217" class=""><a href="/our-services/service-three">Service 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-1125" class=""><a href="/about">About</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-1139" class=""><a href="/events">Events</a></li>
</ul></nav>
```